# Django admin editable field - take action

Tags: django, web, django-models, django-admin, django-views

I have a question:
In Django admin when you have a model with a column (BooleanField) and set it as editable in admin.py. Is it possible when you check & save it to take some action ?
I have an object, lets say Ticket, with various fields and another field named Status.
I see all his fields in Django Admin (register it in admin.py) and when I set his Status to True & save it, I want django admin to send an email lets say ... Is it possible, and if ... how ?
Thank you very much folks & Merry Christmas !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible by overriding the save_model method on the ModelAdmin class. You can find the relevant docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model).

So, given your example, you might do something along the lines of this:

```
from django.contrib import admin

class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if obj.BooleanModelFieldName == True:
            send_email(object.user.email)
        obj.save()
```

You will probably want to ensure the email does not get sent every time the model is saved by including more precise logic within the method, however.